# How can I get applications to display a system tray icon?

Tags: release-loki, release-freya, wingpanel

Many 3rd party applications like Java, NodeWebkit, and Gtk2 applications don't seem to be able to display a system tray icon. Why is that? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### elementary OS does not support GtkStatusIcon (commonly referred to as system tray), and will drop support for the Ayatana Indicator API in the next release.

[GtkStatusIcon](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusIcon.html) (the old API for apps to place icons in the panel) has been deprecated since 2014 and is not implemented in elementary OS. Please file a report with application developers that are still using this API requesting that they make their app function without it.

#### I'm a developer and I want to implement this feature.

Currently (in 0.3 Freya), only the Ayatana Indicator API is respected. However, as of 0.4 Loki, the panel will no longer implement the Ayatana API either. It is [recommended in the elementary HIG](https://elementary.io/docs/human-interface-guidelines#system-indicators) that apps not explicitly use the indicator area at all.

If you're developing a music app, your app will automatically show in the sound indicator as long as it can be controlled through [MPRIS](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/latest/).

If your app [sends notifications](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.Notification), missed notifications will automatically be preserved in the notifications indicator (as of 0.4 Loki).

If you want to present easily accessible actions while your app is closed or not running, [follow the freedesktop.org actions specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#extra-actions).

#### How can I work around this?

Try installing `sni-qt`. This works for some apps:

```
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Another option is to install a panel that supports this old API like `xfce4-panel`.

Comment: How should one call the area where other applications have an icon when started, which behaves just like a tray icon? Example [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/35UBr.png).

Comment: @cipricus "System tray" refers specifically to the GtkStatusIcon API. The apps in your screenshot are using the Ayatana Indicator API (usually called "app indicators"), which is similar but not specifically what is called the "system tray".

Answer (score 6):

To get Slack and other apps to show a system tray-like icon in Wingpanel you have to update the apps `.desktop` file and add `env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity` to the start of the Exec key. Using Slack as an example (this works with every app I tried it on that has a system tray icon) we would do the following:

`sudo nano /usr/share/applications/slack.desktop`

Change the `Exec` key from:
`Exec=/usr/bin/slack --disable-gpu %U`

to:
`Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity /usr/bin/slack --disable-gpu %U`

Comment: Do you have idea how to put Wine System Tray into Wingpanel?

Comment: Rocco, In my Freya slack icon appears in wingpanel in either form of a Exec=(with or without env etc) and it looks relativelly big. Maybe you know how to get rid of it or at least change its size?

Comment: daGo, I unfortunately do not have a copy of Freya on hand to help debug, but you might find some luck editing the `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/apps.css`, `/usr/share/themes/elementary/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` (under Panel in `.panel` or `.composited-indicator`, or `/usr/share/icons/elementary/index.theme` file. Hopefully you find what you are looking for there. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Elementary OS 5 or 6:

Add repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt-get update
```

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

Edit configfile with your editor:

```
 sudo <your editor> /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

Change line `OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;` to `OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;`

Save file and reboot system.

Result:
[image]

Source:
[How to show app indicators on the system tray in elementary OS](https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-show-app-indicators-on-the-system-tray-in-elementary-os/)

**Double wifi icon:**

Disable by renaming this config file:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.old
```

Reboot system to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Install Trayer, a GTK2 tray application:

```
sudo apt install trayer
```

and then add a command similar to this to your session:

```
trayer --expand false --SetDockType false --widthtype pixel --width 200 --align right --iconspacing 15
```

As is typical:

```
trayer --help
```

for parameter help.