# Can I get a panel icon (similar to a systray icon) for Deadbeef - like Clementine and many other programs have?

Tags: release-freya, icons, wingpanel

***Edited after flag and comment to close as duplicate:***

This was marked as a duplicate for asking for a system tray icon while it looks [elementary OS does not have a system tray](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/4227/170). If that is the case, then I do not mean system tray, but the area where other programs have system tray-like icons

[image]

Is it possible to have a Deadbeef icon **like that** in elementary OS - as I have in other desktops environments (and other programs have in elementary OS)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get applications to display a system tray icon?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon)

Comment: @DanielForé - I need to edit the question because I said "system tray" just for convenience but I am referring to the area where some programs like Clementine, uGet, Flareget, Qbittorrent and many many others **do** display an icon, call it systray icon or whatever. The answer to the question to which you have marked this one as duplicate can be resumed by **"elementary OS does not have a system tray"**. Well then: **how can I have a Deadbeef panel icon like Clementine has?**

Comment: "This question may already have an answer here:  [How can I get applications to display a system tray icon?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon)" -- **No, it does not**.

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/4685/170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If deadbeef does not appear in the tray in Freya it is because it is not using the Ayatana Indicator API.

For Freya, you can ask for Ayatana Indicator API support, however in Loki this will also not be available. The linked question [How can I get applications to display a system tray icon?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/how-can-i-get-applications-to-display-a-system-tray-icon) shows several alternatives for future releases.

Comment: that means that Deadbeef should have Ayatana Indicator API support to appear in the tray, which it has not. correct?

Comment: Yes, if deadbeef does not appear in the tray in Freya then it is because it is not using the Ayatana Indicator API.